# How to set a trigger on delete multiple parent and child rows?

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Below are the tables of relevance:

```
Table_B
B_ID(PK)  Name  A_Id
1         A     1
2         B     1

Table_C
C_ID   B_Id(FK)
1      1
2      1
```

Now I want to delete rows from `Table_B` and from its *child* table `Table_C`.
Below is the query I am *firing*:

```
delete from Table_B where A_Id = 1
```

I want to delete all rows from its *child* too. Is it possible with a Trigger? I have made a Trigger on `Table_B`, but it deletes only one row; so I have to run a loop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see the need to use a trigger. You could use two `DELETE`s:

```
DELETE C
FROM Table_C C
INNER JOIN Table_B B
    ON C.B_ID = B.B_ID
WHERE B.A_ID = 1;

DELETE FROM Table_B 
WHERE A_Id = 1;
```

If you want to use a trigger, you can use this code inside:

```
DELETE C
FROM Table_C C
INNER JOIN DELETED B
    ON C.B_ID = B.B_ID;
```

Justa as a note, remember that if you have a foreign key in that table, you could configure it `ON DELETE CASCADE` (but be careful with your `delete`s)

Comment: Well, I tried trigger.